# Filter & Manipulate CurrentImage []

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Please consider the following (I am using Mathematica 8) :

```
mask = DensityPlot[-Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/5], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 4}, 
       Axes -> None, Frame -> None, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
       ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ImageSize -> 512];

       Show[ImageFilter[Mean[Flatten[#]] &, CurrentImage[], 20, 
            Masking -> mask], ImageSize -> 512]
```

using Sjoerd solution on [Can we generate "foveated Image" in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392065/can-we-generate-foveated-image-in-mathematica).

I would like this to be dynamic. Right now it only takes a picture. 
What would be the best way to get this to work "live" without crashing my computer during my presentation ? Could I adjust the refresh rate ? Manipulate the mask ? Stop the "video mode" to take a picture ?

Comment: I get an error when I run your code in V 8.01, "Show::gtype: ImageFilter is not a type of graphics" CurrentImage::checkcam: Mathematica was unable to connect to a camera. Check that a camera is properly connected and that it is not currently in use by another application

Comment: @Nasser Check that a camera is properly connected and that it is not currently in use by another application :)

Comment: @500 You should also indicate in your question that you're using Mma 8 or tag it with [tag:mathematica-8]. I can't try out most of your questions as they don't run on v7 (which I use)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your `Show` in `Dynamic` and it will update as fast as it can. Combine with `Refresh` to set a refresh rate. Or use a [timed background task](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TimedEvaluations.html).

The result is a bit slow though as the handcrafted blur filter takes too long. A better alternative would be something like:

```
mask = DensityPlot[-Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/5], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   Axes -> None, Frame -> None, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
   ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ImageSize -> {320, 240}];

ImageCompose[im = CurrentImage[], SetAlphaChannel[Blur[im, 20], mask]]//Dynamic
```

which updates in real time. Note that I have changed the image dimensions of the mask to fit the size of my laptop camera. The x and y range ratio should be the same as the camera's aspect ratio.

[image]

Remember, as mentioned before, this only *fakes* visual blurring. It is far from reality.

Comment: Thank You Sjoerd. I know it is a rough estimation of visual blurring . I think you would be interested in this : http://www.jeremyfreeman.net/public/downloads/Freeman-Simoncelli-2011-Metamers.pdf

Comment: I am really curious about what you are doing. I browsed your publications and I find similarities with my advisor`s ( http://www.psych.nyu.edu/maloney/ ). What direction are you heading into now ?

Answer (score 1):

Never used a camera with Mma, but it seems that by using [`ImageCapture[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCapture.html) you can specify the Frame Rate and other parameters.

Then use CurrentImage[] in a "loop" to process whatever you want. You can even stop the device from the ImageCapture[] interface.